# how to make a value to be selected in the dropdown selectbox with help of jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to store the select-box value in my cookie.

Users hits the "Default link" then the selected value should be set in cookie. and when they open my URL, then the default selected value should show them.

For this purpose  I have written the below code.but i don't know how can i retrieve the submitted cookie with the name 'language'.

**My doubt**: how can I show the currently submitted cookie value as the  default selected value in my drop-down ?

Please help.

```
    <html>
        <head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#continue').click(function() {
                 var singleValues = $("#select_letter").val();
                $.cookie("language", singleValues);
            })
        });
    </script>  
        </head>
        <body> 
            <select id='select_letter'>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>php</option>
                <option>python</option>
                <option>c sharp</option> 
            </select> 
            <a href='/PhtestProject/index.php' id='continue'>Save as default value</a>
                   <!-- On click of this link the current page will load -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATE**:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#continue').click(function() {
                 var singleValues = $("#select_letter").val(); 
                $.cookie("language", singleValues); 
            }) 

         alert($.cookie('language')); //getting the correct value which are set in cookie
         $('#select_letter option[value="'+$.cookie('language')+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');  //This is not working,Not setting the cookie value as selected

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: add attribute selected="selected" to the option

Comment: On document ready, Check if a cookie is set. if set, use it to make a default select in select box!

Comment: @SankalpMishra You are telling just what i have written in my code. Nothing new

Comment: And where in " your code" have you written it? I am sorry but i am not able to locate it in given snippet.

Comment: @SankalpMishra can you post as answer with code, what extactly you are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick some values on your options:

```
<select id='select_letter'>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="php">php</option>
    <option value="python">python</option>
    <option value="c#">c sharp</option> 
</select>
```

Then store the value selected into your cookie.
When you get it back just use:

```
var languageCookieValue = $.cookie('language');
$('#select_letter option[value="' + languageCookieValue + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The above code would select the Java option.

Comment: how  i will know that value is set in my cookie or not. If "YES" then how can read that value?  your posted code is static `option[value=java]'`. I  am storing the cookie in the name of "language". How can i reterive it back. Please help

Comment: Go here, scroll down to usage, and read: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: your code `$('#select_letter option[value="java"]').attr('selected', 'selected');` is not working . I checked and tested. When i put this code in my javascript function then it is not setting the default value as specified in this code.

Comment: no i did not updated. But now i updated. Its working fine. Please once you edit this answer. I have to increase the vote.